# creating google maps api marker using json data and AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, api, google-maps, instagram

I'm working with the Instagram API and I'm trying to create markers on a Google Map by storing the longitude and latitude from the Instagram pictures in a JSON file.

This is my code from the Instagram API and creating the JSON file

```
<?php
$lat = 51.917367;
$lon = 4.462299;
$client_id = "my-client-id";

$link = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=' . $lat . '&lng=' . $lon . '&client_id=' . $client_id . '&distance=200';
$data = file_get_contents($link);

$result = json_decode($data);


$locations = [];

foreach ($result->data as $post):{
    $images = $post->images->thumbnail->url;
    $latitude = $post->location->latitude;
    $longitude = $post->location->longitude;
    $locations [] = ["longitudes"=>$longitude, "latitudes"=>$latitude, "images"=>$images];
} endforeach;

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($locations);
exit;
```

My question is how do I use AJAX to get the longitude and latitude from the JSON file and then creating a marker (using the image) on this position on the Google Map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that adds markers to google maps, looks like you already have code to get location info in an array, use this code to add it to map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex